# How can i get custom attribute prop's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I use MVC and c# .. how can i get property's value?

Thank you

```
foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(CalcProgressAttribute))))
{

 //i need prop 's value here

}
```

Comment: Try `object value = prop.GetValue(this, null);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to make `GetProperty` work as you expect:

```
foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(CalcProgressAttribute))))
{

 object value = prop.GetValue(this, null);

}
```

I don't know wether your `foreach` loop works, because i can not proof the following part of your code: 
`.Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(CalcProgressAttribute))))`. But without the `Where` the loop will go through all properties.